# Is it possible to have different operator<<() overloads to write to a file and std::cout?

Tags: c++, file, io, operator-overloading, iostream

Edit: Definition of `class TF`:

```
class TF {
    std::vector<V4f> waypoints;
    std::vector<int> densityWaypoints;
public:
    std::size_t size() const { return waypoints.size(); }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const TF& tf);
    friend std::fstream& operator<<(std::fstream& str, const TF& tf);
    // methods here
};
```

The question may steam from the fact that I don't understand streams, so that's probably a precondition.

Is it somehow possible to overload `operator<<(std::ostream, T)` so that when invoked in order to display the data structure on screen, it uses one overload, and when the data structure is written to a file, another one is used? Something like this probably:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const TF& tf) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != tf.waypoints.size(); ++i) {
        str << " { "
            << tf.densityWaypoints[i] << " : "
            << tf.waypoints[i][3] << " : "
            << tf.waypoints[i][0] << " , "
            << tf.waypoints[i][1] << " , "
            << tf.waypoints[i][2]
            << " } ";
    }
    str << "\n";
    return str;
}

std::fstream& operator<<(std::fstream& str, const TF& tf) {
    str << (int)tf.size();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != tf.waypoints.size(); ++i) {
        str << tf.densityWaypoints[i]
            << tf.waypoints[i][0]
            << tf.waypoints[i][1]
            << tf.waypoints[i][2]
            << tf.waypoints[i][3];
    }
```

This doesn't compile with a strange error (I may be tired):

> error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::fstream {aka std::basic_fstream}’ and ‘int’)

The error occurs when I add the second `operator<<()` overload. The first one works fine. Tried both `std::ofstream` and `std::fstream` to the same result.

But I'm not sure if it's going to work either. Sure it's possible to define a function like `int writeTF(std:fstream& str, const TF&tf)`, but that doesn't look C++ enough to me, not to mention the strange error that will potentially appear here, too.

Comment: It's of course possible.

Comment: Could you give us an example where the error occurs. Right now the code you've presented to us doesn't compile for different reasons.

Comment: @0x499602D2 posted a shortcut of the class definition

Comment: You need to provide a minimal, complete example that gives the error provided. When I copy your code to a compiler I don't see the error you say there is.

Comment: Why do you need to differenciate `ostream` an `fstream` actually?

Comment: @0x499602D2 It's minimal, that's the class an object of which I want to output to a file.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I may be misunderstanding the OO design of stream output in C++, but one is a pretty-printer, while the other one is a serializer of sorts to write the object to disk.

Comment: @iksemyonov The 2nd will still write text, and fail miserably to deserialize without any delimiters.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I plan to open it as binary first and then use the operator overload?

Comment: @iksemyonov Opening as binary doesn't change anything about that fact. You'll still write text. You need the `write()` and `read()` functions to de-/serialize binary data. Or even better use a serializaiton library to keep everything portable.

Comment: It seems like you have forgotten to include <fstream> to me.

Comment: Yes indeed it's an <fstream> @StamatisLiatsos. But the question remains: is it possible and typical to have an overload like that?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ do I need to add spaces and newlines for correctness? I've accomplished a similar task once and used newlines together with other delimiters to parse the data file formatted to a certain template.

Comment: @iksemyonov Depends if you want to write text or binary data actually.

Comment: Why all the downvotes, is the question so dumb indeed? The mistake is, but the question itself is not.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ since text is simpler, I'd stick to that. Could you give an answer to the question regarding the overloading?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen code comparing the `ostream`'s address to that of `cout`. I have mixed feelings about it, but it certainly worked:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, Foo const&)
{
    if(&o == &std::cout) {
        return o << "cout";
    } else {
        return o << "not_cout";
    }
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fySNT5vaIxhKIcZr)

Note that `cout` outputs to standard output, it's not the same thing as "the screen".

Comment: @iksemyonov the point is that output can be redirected from the screen to a file with most OS's.